# Why does ocamldebug's install_printer report "Unbound identifier"?

Tags: ocaml, ocamldebug

I've written print functions (print_id, for example) for several types in my program, and have loaded them into ocamldebug (with 'load_printer _build/default/print.cma') but when I try to install them (with 'install_printer print_id' or 'install_printer Print.print_id'), it fails (with 'Unbound identifier print_id' or 'Unbound identifier Print.print_id'). What am I missing?

```
open Error
open Ast

let print_id (Id { name; position }) =
  begin
    Format.open_box 5;
    Format.print_string ("Id { name=" ^ name ^ ";");
    Format.print_space ();
    Format.print_string ("position=" ^ (string_of_position position) ^ " }");
    Format.close_box;
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide additional details to help us help you? Can you show us (presumably) print.ml? If it's a very large source file, cut it down to a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to include formatted code in a comment, so I've added the text of (a minimal version of) print.ml to the original question instead.